# mySQL comparing numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, compare

I'm trying to figure out a way in mySQL to compare a number to a list of numbers to find the the closest one to it.

So in essence if I had the number 5 and the list of numbers 7,8,9,2,1 the answer would be 7.

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Here is what i need this for.
I'm trying to find the nearest station that has a particular service when i provide the current station id that I am at and the service I am looking for.

Here is the code for my stored procedure:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS nearest;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE nearest
    (
        IN serviceIn VARCHAR(20), IN stationid INT
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT station_id
        FROM station
        WHERE ABS(station_id - stationid) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(station_id - stationid))
        FROM station) AND service = serviceIn;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what is your list look like?

Comment: The list is just going contain id's that I selectfrom a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT number
FROM tablename
ORDER BY  ABS(number - 5) 
LIMIT 1;
```

See it in action

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1785/5)

---

But this will always return only one number, but in case there is duplicate numbers that are close with the same number it will get only one of them. For instance if you have the number 3 in your list, in this case the two number 7 and 3 should be returned, the previous query will return only one of them.

For this case, try this:

```
SELECT number
FROM tablename
WHERE ABS(number - 5) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(number - 5))
                         FROM tablename);
```

See it in action:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo for duplicates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01d49/1)

---

### Update:

You will need to add the condition `` to the subquery as well, so that your stored procedure should looks like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS nearest;

CREATE PROCEDURE nearest
(
  IN serviceIn VARCHAR(20), IN stationid INT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT station_id
  FROM station
  WHERE ABS(station_id - stationid) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(station_id - stationid))
                                       FROM station
                                       WHERE service = serviceIn) AND service = serviceIn;
END
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33d2/2)

Comment: @Dermot - You are welcome any time :) and welcome to Stackoverflow :) Glad I could help :) :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Hello again, I just edited my post with what I'm trying to do and I can't seem to get it working. Have you any ideas? Please

Comment: @Dermot What is the error you got from this stored procedure when you tried it?

Comment: It doesn't give an error it runs ok, it just doesn't return anything

Comment: @Dermot - But it is working fine, see this [**example fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b3fa/1)? It might be something wrong else where.

Comment: That's really strange. So the logic is definitly right with it then

Comment: @Dermot Can you please edit this [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b3fa/1) with the real data and the real table structure and show that issue that is not working in your context? it will be very helpful to track the problem that you had. Also try to run the query directly in MySQL, and ensure that it is working fine. Then the problem might be else where in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's the link to create the tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03491 and the link to populate them http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03491/1. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dermot - Sorry for late, I was fixing the data, note that the way you are inserting into the tables isn't correct, I hope you aren't inserting into your tables the same way. For SQL Fiddle Demo, for future usage, you can create the tables easily from the `Text to DDL` button then paste the data, then it will automatically create the tables and populate them automatically.  See my edit for the issue you mentioned, is this right now?

Comment: @Dermot - Also, you didn't need that column `line` in the `station` table, because the `zone` column already linked to a specific `line` in the `zone` table, then you didn't need it in the `station` table.

Comment: @Dermot - Sorry see my answer, there is a section with title `UPDATE` this is the updated section see it with the fix to the stored procedure. And the updated SQL Fiddle Demo, it is this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33d2/2

Comment: It's finally working for me now Mahmoud, thankyou very much for all your help with this!!!!

Comment: @Dermot - No it is not. As I understood your question you need to find the nearest station_id for a specific service? right? So, if you take a look, you will find that, for example, for the service `parking` [**there are 4 services**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33d2/7) `1, 6, 37, 39`, if you tested it with [`CALL nearest('parking', 5);`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33d2/2) it will give you station_id 6, if you test it with [`CALL nearest('parking', 30);`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33d2/8) it will give you station_id 37, and so on, isn't that right?

Comment: @Dermot You're welcome any time, Good Night :) If you need anything later, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion earlier I must not of looked at it correctly..thanks again you were a great help!!

Comment: @Dermot Its OK, no problem. Finally I can go to sleeeeep :)